# Analytic continuation of Zeta type function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

Can one analytically continue the function (Not equal to the Zeta function)

$$Z(s)=\prod_{p}\frac{1}{1+p^{-s}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{\Omega(k)}}{k^s}$$
Where $\Omega(k)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $k$.

Specifically, can one find $Z(0)$?

Comment: You can go from the infinite product to the infinite sum, and then analytically continue it.

Comment: Well, I started with the infinite sum, didn't know how to continue it, so I converted it to the product and posted it here. How would you continue the infinite Dirichlet series?

Comment: I asked this a time ago, here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378803/zeta-function-zeros-and-analytic-continuation I think it will be useful

Comment: Oh, you must've seen the "+" sign as a "-". This is NOT the Zeta function

Comment: Hmm, yeap, Sorry!

Comment: In fact, $\Omega(k)$ is not the number of *distinct* prime factors of $k$; it is the *total* number of prime factors.  E.g., $\Omega(9)=2$.  With this adjustment, the OP's identity is correct, as is the answer below.  BTW, $(-1)^{\Omega(k)}$ is called Liouville's function, denoted $\lambda(k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Z(s)=\frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)}$$