# Value of polylogarithms $\mathrm{Li}_s(1)$ for $s<1$.

Tags: polylogarithm, analytic-continuation

For real $s>1$ the polylogarithm for $z=1$ reduces to the Riemann zeta function $\mathrm{Li}_s(1) = \zeta(s)$. For real $s<1$ Wolfram Alpha and the Wolfram function site give $\mathrm{Li}_s(1) = \infty, s<1$ whereas the mpmath package returns $\mathrm{Li}_s(1) = \zeta(s)$ for all $s\ne 1$. Is this just a convention or is it a kind of continuation for $s?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) and [zeta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) functions with the series :$$\operatorname{Li}_s(z):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {z^k}{k^s}\\\zeta(s):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{k^s}$$
then you'll be in the first case and have to suppose $\;\Re(s)>1\;$ for convergence but if you consider the [analytic continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) of these two series as being the actual functions then things become much more interesting and considering every complex $s$ such that $\;s\ne 1\;$ should be the fine choice (see the discussions in the Wikipedia links or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378803/zeta-function-zeros-and-analytic-continuation) concerning zeta).

Comment: Would $\mathrm{Li}_s(1) = \zeta(s)$ for $s \ne 1$ be  **the** analytic continuation, because this relation holds for $\Re s >1$?

Comment: Yes @gammatester. From the equality for $\Re s >1$ and since $\zeta$ admits a unique analytic continuation over the whole complex plane except $s=1$ we must have the equality for $s\neq 1$ (else $\operatorname{Li}_s(1)$ would not be analytic in $s$ !).