# Does the following series converge uniformly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, divergent-series

I know how to show that the following series will converge absolutely. But am unsure how to show it will or will not converge uniformly for $z\in (0,1).$

$\displaystyle \sum_{n \mathop = 1}^{\infty} \left( {\frac 1 {(z+n)^{1/2}}}-{\frac 1 {n^{1/2}}}\right)$

Comment: What is the domain for $z$?

Comment: Sorry, z is Real, and in the interval form (0,1)

Comment: Well i used this other article found on stack exchange http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221994/riemann-zeta-function-manipulation/222588#222588 ... I'll post that instead of rewriting it. He's showing it for Dirichlet Eta but its generally the same for what i need.

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$\frac{1}{(z+n)^{1/2}}-\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}=\frac{n^{1/2} - (z+n)^{1/2}}{n^{1/2} (z+n)^{1/2}}$$

By the mean value theorem, $(z+n)^{1/2}=n^{1/2} + \frac{\xi_n}{2 n^{1/2}}$, where $\xi_n \in (0,1)$. Also $(z+n)^{1/2} \geq n^{1/2}$. Putting things together, the numerator is at most $\frac{1}{2 n^{1/2}}$ in magnitude while the denominator is at least $n$. Can you finish now?

Comment: lol yes i think so, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

We have $$0>\sum_{n\geq1}\left(\frac{1}{\left(z+n\right)^{1/2}}-\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq1}\int_{n}^{n+z}\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}dx\geq-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq1}\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}dx>$$ $$-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}>-\infty.
 $$ If you prefer, we can use directly the M- test with the same passages $$\left|\frac{1}{\left(z+n\right)^{1/2}}-\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}\right|=\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}-\frac{1}{\left(z+n\right)^{1/2}}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{n}^{n+z}\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}dx\leq\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}.
 $$

Comment: -.5 Zeta(1.5) > - (infinity)?

Comment: $\zeta(1.5)< \infty $? If you prefer, we can show it in the positive situation, it's the same.

Comment: Im so sorry i read the inequalities incorrectly. I apologize.

Comment: @T.Poindexter No problem! ;)

Comment: @MarcoCantarini How  do $-\frac{1}{2}$ $ \sum_{n =1}^{\infty}$$ \int_{n}^{n+z}$ $\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}dx$ $\ge$ $-\frac{1}{2}$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $ \int_{n}^{n+1}$ $\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}dx$ come? Please help me.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan Note that $z \in (0,1)$ and the integrand is positive.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini Then, [n,n+z] is smaller interval no than [n, n+1] then, negative sign is reverting the inequality, right?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan Right.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** showing [normal convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence) is usually easier, and a sufficient condition for uniform convergence.
(when and *if* the test for normal convergence fails, then it is time to start thinking about the bad possible situation — that there may be uniform convergence nevertheless.)

Comment: I think this would be more helpful if $z$ were complex, but it is evidently real (and positive).

Comment: @Ian -- the method still can apply: the $\sup$ termwise is attained for $z=1$, and the corresponding series does converge.

Comment: Fair point, though then the estimation from there is the same as the estimation I did anyway :)

Comment: @Ian True :) ${}$

Comment: Well generally i would have liked z to be an element of the complex open unit disk with deleted origin, but really its immaterial as Z as a real variable was sufficient for what i needed